# Why doesn't Magento setHeader('application/json') when appropriate in OnePageCheckout?

Tags: magento-1.9, json, apache2

I have a Magento environment that is tunneled through Apache via mod_proxy. During the one-page checkout process, Apache is erroneously wrapping JSON responses in HTML because the response header says "text/html" for "content-type", which it clearly isn't.

I'm pretty much planning on adding..

`$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');`

... before every instance of ...

`$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));`

...within the methods of **Mage_Checkout_OnepageController**. But that's a core hack and I have to wonder about the side-effects of such a thing.

Magento DOES put a proper **application/json** header before every JSON response in **Mage_Checkout_CartController**, why isn't that the case for **Mage_Checkout_OnepageController**?

Comment: This is a fair question, but the context of "why" is only answerable by core developers so therefore may be slightly off topic. The shortest answer is "because that's how it was built 8 years ago and that's how it will be forever because 1.x won't be updated".  That said, there's not really any harm here because the content body contains parseable text either way.

Comment: I should add, it's not really harmful in most situations. In your situation it seems necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Please add

$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json' , true);

instead of

$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');